# How do I clear the results of the previous option selected after clicking on a new option. It keeps appending itself to the previous option

Tags: javascript, html

I want to clear the previous section when a new option is selected. I want the questions to show one at a time.

The html

```
<form> 
    <select id="changequestion" onchange="activatechangequestion()">
    <option value="1">What is Y% of X</option>
    <option value="2">X is Y% of what</option>
    </select>

    <section id="question1" hidden>
        What is <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Y"> % of <input type="text" name="" placeholder="X" >  
    </section>
    <section id="question2" hidden>
        <input type="text" name="" placeholder="X"> is <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Y"> % of what?  
    </section>
</form>
```

The javascript

```
var tfield1=document.getElementById("textfield1");
var tfield2=document.getElementById("textfield2");
var rfield=document.getElementById("resultfield");
var form=document.getElementById("formcalculate");

function activatechangequestion(){
var changequestion=document.getElementById("changequestion").value;
var getQuestionNumber= parseInt(changequestion);

switch(getQuestionNumber){
    case 1:
        document.getElementById("question1").removeAttribute("hidden");                 
    break;

    case 2:
        document.getElementById("question2").removeAttribute("hidden"); 
    break;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe changing your JavaScript to the following will accomplish the desired functionality:

```
    var tfield1=document.getElementById("textfield1");
    var tfield2=document.getElementById("textfield2");
    var rfield=document.getElementById("resultfield");
    var form=document.getElementById("formcalculate");

    function activatechangequestion(){
        var changequestion=document.getElementById("changequestion").value;
        var getQuestionNumber= parseInt(changequestion);

        switch(getQuestionNumber){
            case 1:
                document.getElementById("question1").removeAttribute("hidden");
                document.getElementById("question2").setAttribute("hidden", "hidden");              
            break;

            case 2:
                document.getElementById("question2").removeAttribute("hidden"); 
                document.getElementById("question1").setAttribute("hidden", "hidden");
            break;
        }
    }
```

In each case statement whichever questions you wish to not be shown add the following:

```
document.getElementById("question[NUMBER]").setAttribute("hidden", "hidden");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I later found a workaround, manipulated it with CSS.